# Facebook could not post to wall facebook error 1367001

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

This self answer is the result of agonizing over the **deprecated** facebook sharer url based api, which kept refusing to post the URL I had setup through the sharer URL format.  The resultant response was the following no matter what privacy setting I set:

```php
{
    "__ar":1,
    "error":1367001,
    "errorSummary":"Could not post to Wall",
    "errorDescription":"The message could not be posted to this Wall.",
    "payload":null,
    "bootloadable":{},
    "ixData":[]
}
```

My mess of code. (Yes it breaks every convention known to web development and yes I inherited this code.)

```php
<?php
    $url = urlencode(Domain::getDomain()."/".$details['urlname']);
    $title=urlencode($details['name']);
    $summary=$details['name'];
    $image=urlencode(constant('BASE_IMAGES').'/'.$details['gallery']['listing'][0]['thumb']['src']); 
?>

<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325'); return false" href="javascript: void(0)"><img src="/site/images/icon-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" border="0"></a>
```

The official question is as follows: Why does the sharer method of sharing links in facebook result in this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case, this was because I had not included the fully qualified URL including the protocol.  My PHP generated URL was a mess of concatenation and did not include the protocol.  After adding it, the post went through.

I had to change the second line listed above to

```php
    $url = urlencode('http://'.Domain::getDomain()."/".$details['urlname']);
```

There could be more reasons why Facebook throws this `1367001 Error`, but this is at least one thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Please start your Url with http://
eg : http://www.google.com

May be there might be Url validations been performed at their (FB's)end hence start with Protocol name and  end with domain name (com,co.in, ie)
This fixed my issue :)